# How do I remove subtract symble in Formula Field?

Tags: formula-field, date, fields

I'm trying to remove the subtract symble from a formula field. This formula field is based on a two fields. one is date field value anthoer one is Text filed value. Is that a possibility?

My scenario:

TEXT((TODAY() - (DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)- VALUE(Daysonrecord__c))))

```
TODAY()=10/10/2017
CreatedDate=6/10/017
Daysonrecord__c=19 ==>  (10-(6-19))=(10-(-13))=23
```

Actuvally Excpecting answer is *(10-(6-19)) = (10-(-13)) = 3*.

how to remove substract symbol before '**-13**'. How can i achieve my expected answer *3*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `ABS` function in the formula. This will return the absolute value for you.

So, something like this should work for you.

```
ABS(TEXT(ABS(TODAY() - ABS(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)- ABS(VALUE(Daysonrecord__c))))))
```

**Note: This is just a pseudo code. You need to try it out.**

Comment: @Hemanth Jain, Not working above Formula Field. I got this ERROR

" Custom Field Definition Edit
 
Error: Invalid Data.
Review all error messages below to correct your data.
Incorrect parameter type for function 'ABS()'. Expected Number, received Date (Related field: Formula) "

Comment: ABS accepts only number parameter, so you will have to convert the number into date first.

Comment: @Hemanth Jain, I am also getting same error.

Comment: @Hemanth Jain, I dinn get you. How to convert the number into date

Comment: You can convert the Date to number using the 'DAY' function like, DAY(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)) and DAY(TODAY())